# Laravel update only the changed field attribute(s)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to run this update function in my laravel controller. Here my domain name is an unique attribute.

**The problem**

But now every time when I'm trying to update any field rather than domain name field, it showing me an error saying domain name is already existing. So how can I update only the fields which have been changed? what changes do I need to be made in the following function.

```
public function update(Request $request,Website $app, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'subDomainName' => ['required'],
            'subDomainSuffix' =>['required'], 
            'packageType'=>['required'],
            'themeid'=>['required'],
            'lang'=>['required'],
            'user'=>['required'],
            'domain' => ['required', 'string','min:2', 'max:255','unique:apps'],
        ],$request->all());

        $fullDomain = $request->domain;
        $app->domain=$fullDomain;
        Website::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Website updated successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify a model to be ignored](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) on the unique attribute:

```
public function update(Request $request, Website $websiteModel, int $id)
{
    $website = $websiteModel->find($id);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'subDomainName' => ['required'],
        'subDomainSuffix' => ['required'], 
        'packageType' => ['required'],
        'themeid' => ['required'],
        'lang' => ['required'],
        'user' => ['required'],
        'domain' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:2',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique('apps')->ignore($website)
         ],
    ], $request->all());

    $website->update($request->all());

    return redirect()
        ->route('customers.index')
        ->with('success','Website updated successfully');
}
```

Don't forget to import `Rule`: `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`